# Weird OnItemClick Behavior (GridView in a Fragment)

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm trying to 1) reveal a view and 2) modify another view in response to a user click on a view. The clickable view is populated by an adapter and set to a GridView. In my code, mTextView is a reference to another view in rootView. There are no NullPointer errors.

The strange problems are

1. In my code, for whatever method I call with LINE 3's mTextView, let it be setVisibility() or whatnot, LINE3 will draw (Shows changed text HELLO WORLD in at the other view), but LINE 1 just won't draw. The strange behavior is, with LINE 3, when I click the item the second time, LINE 1 works.
2. When I comment LINE 3 out, LINE 1 works on the first click. So, LINE 1's view is obviously not NULL (or could it?)
3. Yet another strange behavior is, LINE 2 always work as expected, the background color changed the first click, with or without LINE 3.
4. Each LINE1,LINE2 or LINE3 work perfectly on its own, in onItemClick.

What baffles me is why does LINE2 work but not LINE1, what are the possible dependencies between LINE3, LINE2, LINE1. Here is the code.

```
// Setup OnItemClickListener to respond to user click
mCardsGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     // store the selected favor item as an instance, if it is not set already
            mSelectedGameCardItem = (GameCardItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

     // Make the content visible (LINE 1)
            view.findViewById(R.id.game_card_item_title).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     // Change the background color (LINE 2)
            view.findViewById(R.id.game_card_item).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorAccent));

     // change tag line message at another view, rootView(LINE 3)
mTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.favors_game_post_game_description, "HELLO WORLD"));
            }
        }
    });
```

The XML of the item_card layout, this layout is used by the adapter to inflate the item in the grid.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/game_card_item"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorLightPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mysterious_box_36dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game_card_item_title"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:text="@string/favors_default_1" />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I suggest that you include the layout, it sounds like the background may, when set, be covering/hiding the title. Perhaps check using the design view if using Android Studio by setting the background.

Comment: @MikeT I've included the xml for each item in the GridView in the OP. Thanks for your response. I know I'm definitely missing something, but LINE 1 and LINE 2 would work perfectly fine without LINE 3 (has nothing to do with the background or title or any views in the xml above) LINE 1 item's title becomes visible, and LINE 2 changed the item's background color when the item is clicked.